# requests.get(proxies=proxies) does't work,why?

Tags: python-requests, web-crawler, proxies

I want to set the proxy IP with requests.get, but the console output is my own IP, I would like to ask Crawler Engineers, how to solve?
the imgeis my code

[image: 1]

Comment: do you mind posting code instead of screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I tried using your proxy but i did not work so tried diffrent proxy from web
and it work
i can try

```
import requests

url  ="http://httpbin.org/get"

ip = "119.129.239.236:4245"
proxies  =  {
   "http": "http://130.41.55.190:8080",
    "https":"https://130.41.55.190:8080"
}

response  =  requests.get(url,proxies=proxies)

print(response.json())
```